# ORA-06502 Error Only in SQLPLUS

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have an Oracle 11 database on a development server. I'm trying to execute a stored procedure:

```
declare
    date_start varchar2(15);
    date_end varchar2(15);
begin
    Fecha_inicio := '01/01/2014';
    Fecha_fin := '01/01/2016';
    FCBK.PKG_PACKAGE.Generate(Fecha_inicio,Fecha_fin);
end;
```

If I execute the procedure from SQL Developer or from SQL*Plus on my personal Windows machine, the procedure has no problem.

If I execute the procedure from SQL*Plus in the development server (IBM AIX Machine), the procedure ends with this error:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
```

Comment: Without seeing the procedure code and the full error stack it's impossible to tell. Since you are using dates I'd *guess* this is (yet another) NLS issue, with different session settings on the two platforms.

Comment: what param types method FCBK.PKG_PACKAGE.Generate?

Comment: Presumably, PKG_PACKAGE.Generate() tries to convert the argument strings into date values, which might fail due to different NLS settings (as mentioned by Alex Poole). Please add the procedure code, your NLS settings and the error stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Was a internal error of the package. Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by a difference between the NLS configuration of the 2 SQL clients. A quick check could be to first run

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy'
```

or otherwise include

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = ''dd/mm/yyyy''';
```

in your procedure.

To check your current NLS settings, query the "nls_session_parameters" table which lists the configuration of the current user session.

```
SELECT *
FROM   nls_session_parameters
```

Comment: nls_session_parameters is probably more useful. But better to use explicit date models rather than rely on or change NLS settings. If that is in fact what is wrong; could be a character set problem too, perhaps. Very hard to tell.

Comment: I try this, but the problem persist. I try too to put a to_date(,'DD/MM/YYYY') but the error persist.